# How would I launch a program in a smaller window, rather than use GetDesktopWindow?

Tags: c++, window, fullscreen, desktop

Currently I am launching a program that takes up the whole window and I have to wait for it to finish its test to get access to the rest of the screen. Below is the code that implements this:

```
    CWnd * pWnd = GetDesktopWindow(); //Where the screen gets taken up

    CRect rect;

    pWnd->GetClientRect(&rect);
    
    MoveWindow(&rect, TRUE);
    InvalidateRect(&rect, TRUE);
    UpdateWindow();
```

CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx seems to be useful but wanted to ask generally if anyone had any further input. Thank you!

Comment: are you launching 3rd party program from your code and want the program to be not in full screen mode?
Or you're launching your own program and want the program to take less space on the desktop screen?
CRect structure contains left,top,right,bottom coordinates which you can adjust to movewindow to desired shape and position
P.S
Have a look at SetWindowPos function

Comment: @AlexanderSobetskiy I am launching my own program and I want it to be in a window that takes up less space, but can be moved around as well, rather than be locked into one spot. I did try those functions, it seems as if the screen is being taken over at a different point, I am now combing through various 'Rect' and 'CRect' to find the correct one